# Ruby on Rails variable in Javascript without quotes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, kml

I work with Ruby on Rails and I want to use a Ruby variable in Javascript on my Index view.

Here the Ruby Code:

```
def kml

require 'ruby_kml'

kml = KMLFile.new
folder = KML::Folder.new(:name => 'Melbourne Stations')
[
    ["Berlin1", 52.520645, 13.409779],
    ["Berlin2", 52.520645, 13.409779],
    ["Berlin3", 13.409779, 52.520645],
].each do |name, lat, lng|
  folder.features << KML::Placemark.new(
      :name => name,
      :geometry => KML::Point.new(:coordinates => {:lat => lat, :lng =>      lng})
  )
end
kml.objects << folder

@kml = kml.render

return kml
end
```

In this variable is the following string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"> 
<Folder><name>Melbourne Stations</name> 
<Placemark><name>Berlin1</name>
<Point><coordinates>13.409779,52.520645</coordinates></Point></Placemark> 
<Placemark><name>Berlin2</name>
<Point><coordinates>13.409779,52.520645</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><name>Berlin3</name>
<Point><coordinates>52.520645,13.409779</coordinates></Point></Placemark>  
</Folder> </kml>
```

And in Javascript I want to use this KML in the following Code:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.KML({
            extractStyles: false
        })).readFeatures('<%= kml.render.to_json %>',{
                    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
                    featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
                } )
    })
});
```

But the Problem is, that at the top and the bottom of the Code Javascript or Ruby creates double quotes and the Javascript can't read it with quotes.

So what do I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try `<%=j kml.render.to_json %>`

Comment: Yeah I tried. But it don't worked :/

Comment: Try `<%=raw kml.render.to_json %>`

Comment: If I use raw it puts real quotes (") instead of &quot;... But it only works without " or &quot;

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the Problem myself... :D I just added the following Javascript Code:

```
var kml = '<%=raw @kml.to_json %>';

kml = kml.replace("\"", "");
```

So I created a Javascript Variable and the just replaced the quotes... Too easy -.-